# WEB API 2.2: ApiController Unauthorized Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a ASP.NET web application which contains both MVC and WEB API. Can anyone give me an example of how to use ApiController.Unauthorized Method in Web API. I am not sure what kind of parameter I should pass into this method.

Comment: do you want to implement authentication?

Comment: Hi Sandeep. Yes, I do want to implement authentication but don't want to write a custom authentication filter.

Comment: you can create message handler for authentication. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/basic-authentication-in-web-api-based-on-user-role/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your controller action method return `IHttpActionResult` then you can use this method as return type.

```
return Unauthorized();
```

You can also pass `AuthenticationHeaderValue` as parameter of this method which represents authentication information in Authorization, ProxyAuthorization, WWW-Authneticate, and Proxy-Authenticate header values.

If your action method does not return `IHttpActionResult` then you can throw `HttpResponseException` in anywhere from your controller action.

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

If you want to pass a custom message then use

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) 
{ 
    ReasonPhrase = "Your message!" 
};
throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```